# MySQL root user with no password (on local dev) stopped permitting access after update

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL running on a virtual machine on my laptop within a host only network (no access to the wider internet except when I turn on the NAT interface to update the O/S). For convenience, I have the root user with no password. I have a number of projects that are setup to access the database this way within my development environment.

I just did an `apt-get upgrade`, which included updating MySQL to 5.7.18 (I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS) and now all of my projects are getting access denied. I am not sure which version MySQL was at before the update.

From the console, I can `mysql --user=root` with no problems if I am logged in as root, but not if I am logged in as anyone else.

Can anyone help determine what the update changed and how I can configure MySQL to allow root user access with no password again?

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/) from Percona might help you.  Also check out [this post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/18/where-is-the-mysql-5-7-root-password/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the update changed the plugin for root@localhost or if the plugin remained unchanged and MySQL's behavior changed, but I resolved this problem by changing the plugin for root@localhost to `mysql_native_password` with the following SQL:

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```